# Amazon S3 sink option is Disabled in Azure DataFlow. How to enable it?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am creating a new DataFlow in Azure Data Factory.
I want to read a filestream column from sql server and upload it to S3 bucket for POC purpose.

I created Azure DataFlow, Added Amzaon S3 Linked Service and Verified the connection.
Now, Amazon S3 option is available for Selecting Source but I need to set it into Sink.
**When I add a new Sink then Amazon S3 option is disabled there (see screenshot).**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjFd2.png)

Comment: Amazon S3 as sink in ADF copy activity or mapping data flow is not available. Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview).

Comment: Thanks @Aswin, Now I am able to understand the reason

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores), Currently Amazon S3 is only supported as Source and not as sink in ADF dataflow.

You can raise the feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).

As an alternative, you can try copying the data using other services like databricks or functions by configuring the connections.

Or If you can connect your Amazon SFTP to s3 bucket to copy the data to it, you can try the below method.

Transform the input data to amazon sftp first. Then use this as per your requirement to copy the data to your S3 bucket. In the sink of the dataflow, use sftp dataset.

[image]

Go through this [blob](https://aws.plainenglish.io/aws-sftp-server-with-aws-s3-c27ef664432e) by @**Sena Yakut** to learn about getting files from aws sftp to S3.